# Video Stream Tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, video-streaming

I'm working with a thermography camera to stream video into a Tkinter GUI. When I tested it with cv2.imshow, the stream was perfect. However, when I integrate the video into the Tkinter GUI, it gets cut off, for sure i didnt use the open cv stream function coz i wasnt able to integrate it into the gui

```
cv2.namedWindow("Image Stream", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while True :
    himage = grab_camera_image_rt(htgrab, 150)
    
    cv2.imshow('Image Stream', process_img(himage=himage))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # press q to quit
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
this function stream the video well
```

this is the process function :

```
def process_img(himage):
    try:
        width=get_image_width(himage)
        height=get_image_height(himage)
        count=width*height
        ptr = (ctypes.c_uint16 * count)()
        ctypes.memmove(ptr, get_image_data_pointer(himage), get_image_data_length(himage))
        buffer_data = np.asarray(ptr, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((height, width))
        image = cv2.normalize(buffer_data, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
        
    except:
        print("error Converting Image")
        time.sleep(0.01)
    return image
```

and this is the new method used to integrate the output of process _img with the tkinter GUI :

```
def video_update_loop(self):
 
    while True:
        try:
            
            himage = f.grab_camera_image_rt(self.htgrab, 150)
            frame = f.process_img(himage=himage)
            print("camera connected successfully")
            frame = Image.fromarray(frame, mode="L")
            self.current_frame = ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame)
            
 
            self.video_label.after(5, self.update_video_label_image)
        except:
            
            print("Error updating the video frame.Retrying...")
            
            
            
            time.sleep(1)
```

my question is there a solution to perfectly stream the video ?
PS: the procedure of grabbing video should be like this : we grab pictures from camera and we process them to get the video

Comment: I recommend that you begin with a hello world GUI example to clearly understand what gui programming is before you start to develop such a big task. Check what means **Event driven architecture** and why you should avoid blocking functions...Also take a closer look what **after()** rly means...

Comment: your answer is so helpful thank you